# Listening to an event from my greasemonkey script

Tags: javascript, firefox, greasemonkey

I'm trying to figure out how to listen to an event emitter from my greasemonkey script, but I keep getting access violation errors (`Permission denied to access object`).

**Page**
The page contains a simple event emitter:

```js
var emitter = function(){
    this.events = {};
}

emitter.prototype.on = function(eventName, closure){
    this.events[eventName] = this.events[eventName] || [];
    this.events[eventName].push(closure);
};

emitter.prototype.emit = function(eventName, data){
    if(this.events[eventName]){
        this.events[eventName].forEach(function(fn){
            return fn(data);
        });
    }
}

var test = new emitter();
test.emit('test', {data:'test'});
```

**Script**
This throws an access violation error (this used to work a while ago, but I guess it got patched or something):

```
unsafeWindow.test.on('test', function(data){
    console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: Do you have `// @grant unsafeWindow` in userscript metablock?

Comment: @wOxxOm Yes. unsafeWindow works just fine.

Comment: Try exporting the function into unsafe context: `unsafeWindow.test.on('test', exportFunction(function(data){ .... }))`

Comment: @wOxxOm YES! `unsafeWindow.test.on('test', exportFunction(function(data){}, unsafeWindow))` did the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to get it working. The solution was to export the callback function into unsafe context via `exportFunction(myFunction, unsafeWindow)`

The script part should look like this:

```
unsafeWindow.test.on('test', exportFunction(function(data){
   console.log(data);
}, unsafeWindow));
```

Big thanks to [wOxxOm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3959875/woxxom) for pointing this out.