# Can't use required library when an @grant value is set

Tags: javascript, firefox, greasemonkey, userscripts, stackexchange-api

There are a few questions relating to this, but the general 'solution' of using `unsafeWindow` isn't working for me.

I'm trying to use the [Stack Exchange Javascript SDK](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/js-lib).

This works:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        testing
// @include     http://stackoverflow.com/*
// @require     https://api.stackexchange.com/js/2.0/all.js
// @version     1
// @grant       none
// ==/UserScript==

console.log(SE);
SE.init({
  clientId: 1234,
  key: 'my key',
  channelUrl: location.protocol + '//stackoverflow.com/blank',
  complete: function (d) {
    console.log(d);
    console.log('SE init');
  }
});
```

This doesn't:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        testing
// @include     http://stackoverflow.com/*
// @require     https://api.stackexchange.com/js/2.0/all.js
// @version     1
// @grant       GM_setValue
// ==/UserScript==

console.log(SE);
SE.init({
  clientId: 1234,
  key: 'my key',
  channelUrl: location.protocol + '//stackoverflow.com/blank',
  complete: function (d) {
    console.log(d);
    console.log('SE init');
  }
});
```

However, both versions log `Object { authenticate: n(), init: r() }` for the `console.log(SE)` which I can't understand because it means the script has access to the SE object.

By "doesn't work", I mean it does nothing; nothing is logged to the console after the first `console.log(SE)`.

I don't understand how to get this library to work. Does anyone have any ideas? This is relating to the sandbox that is enabled on Firefox when a grant value is set.

This does, by the way, work on Chrome either way, but my understanding is that the 2 sandboxes are considerably different. Is there any way to get around this Firefox sandbox that is preventing the `SE.init()` function to run? I've tried `unsafeWindow.SE...` but that doesn't work -- I don't think it should make a difference because the script always has access to the SE object; it's just having trouble actually calling it!

Comment: Your function should be exported into the webpage context: [Listening to an event from my greasemonkey script](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38357589)

Comment: @wOxxOm hmm I'm trying `exportFunction(SE, unsafeWindow, {defineAs: 'SE'});` but that doesn't seem to work :/

Comment: @wOxxOm even exporting that function within the complete does nothing: `complete: exportFunction(function (d) { console.log(d); console.log('SE init');   }, unsafeWindow)`. It's as if the code doesn't actually pass the SE.init start!

Comment: Ah, the SE javascript API library you use doesn't export its functions, so I guess either find one that does or adapt it manually. There might be a full source code somewhere. I've added a stackexchange-api tag, but if no one will solve this issue, you can also ask on meta, I guess.

Comment: This is probably a case where you need to *inject* the API code and then use `unsafewindow`, messaging, and/or exported functions to interact with it.

Comment: @wOxxOm, [here is the API source code](https://dev.sstatic.net/apiv2/js/all.js).  One of these days, I will polish up my JS library and publish it. (maybe; been on my rainy day list for years. ;)

Comment: PS: It shouldn't work in Tampermonkey either, but there is a bug in TM's sandboxing. It's possibly a security hole that would allow rogue pages to execute GM_ functions.  Need to investigate, one of these days...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**A quick hack** would be to inject your entire code, including the simple-API script, into webpage and use messaging (dispatchEvent + addEventListerner for 'message' event on window object) to access `GM_` functions that aren't available for an injected script.

It's not as secure as a GM sandbox: the API key can be intercepted via DOM mutation observer / listener or `onbeforescriptexecute` event listener if you have installed an extension or userscript that is specifically targeted to steal the key.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        testing
// @include     http://stackoverflow.com/*
// @include     https://stackoverflow.com/*
// @resource    SE_JS_API https://api.stackexchange.com/js/2.0/all.js
// @version     1
// @grant       GM_setValue
// @grant       GM_getResourceText
// ==/UserScript==

document.head.appendChild(document.createElement('script')).text =
  GM_getResourceText('SE_JS_API') + ';(' + function() {
    SE.init({
      clientId: 1234,
      key: 'my key',
      channelUrl: location.protocol + '//stackoverflow.com/blank',
      complete: function (d) {
        console.log(d);
        console.log('SE init');
      }
    });
  } + ')(); this.remove();'
```

The API script is declared as a resource so that it's downloaded only once, when the script is installed, and stored on the user's hard drive alongside the script.

Alternatively, inject the API and call it via `unsafeWindow` and `exportFunction` for your callbacks:

```
document.head.appendChild(document.createElement('script')).text =
  GM_getResourceText('SE_JS_API');

unsafeWindow.SE.init({
  clientId: 1234,
  key: 'my key',
  channelUrl: location.protocol + '//stackoverflow.com/blank',
  complete: exportFunction(function (d) {
    console.log(d);
    console.log('SE init');
  }, unsafeWindow),
});
```

---

**A proper solution** is to access the [actual API](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs) manually via GM_xmlhttpRequest until someone publishes a better library. In Tampermonkey you'll also need to add a permission for the API url:
`// @connect api.stackexchange.com`.

Comment: I don't think `GM_xmlhttpRequest` will help in this case.  To authenticate, you actually open a new window and use messaging to communicate between the target page and the auth domain.  `GM_xmlhttpRequest` can't (easily) do what's needed.